# error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value in Fibonacci sequence by dynamic programming in C++

Tags: c++, fibonacci, lvalue

I am trying to write a program for generating Fibonacci sequence by dynamic programming approach as follows.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>

int fib(int index)
{
    int memo[] = {0};
    memo[0] = 0;
    memo[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 2; i <= index; i++)
    {
        fib(index) = fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);   //error comes here
    }
    return fib(index);
}
int main()
{   
    time_t start, end, diff;
    int index;
    std::cout << "Please, enter the index of fibonacci sequence" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> index;
    start = time(NULL);
    std::cout << "calculating...." << std::endl << fib(index) <<std::endl;
    end = time(NULL);
    diff = (time_t)difftime(end, start);
    std::cout << "Time elapsed: " << diff << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But, in the line `fib(index) = fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);` Iam getting error as

```
error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value
```

So, please tell me what's wrong I have done in that line. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably there should be a memo[index] instead of fib(index)

Comment: Don't assign to `fib(index)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning to an l-value (which is what `int fib(int)` returns). Just like the error message states.

Also note that `int memo[] = {0};` creates an array of size `1`, so writing beyond index `0` is invalid.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I modified that to `int memo[] = {}`. But, then it returned error that `error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0`.

Comment: @yuvi you can't easily resize arrays in C++. Use a `std::vector`.

Comment: Don't use naked arrays, use std::vector<int> and memo[0] = 1;

Comment: I used vector instead of array. Now, the program is compiling successfully; but it is not executing. It states that `Expression: vector subscript out of range`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to `fib(index)` as others pointed out already. There is workaround by returning reference or pointer.

But the program itself is wrong as it goes into infinite loop. The line

```
fib(index) = fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);
```

Keeps launching fib(index) if index > 1. The correct way of solving Fibonacci using DP is

```
int fib(int n)
{
  int a = 0, b = 1, c, i;
  if( n == 0)
    return a;
  for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
  {
     c = a + b;
     a = b;
     b = c;
  }
  return b;
}
```

Comment: I know that method. But, I have been told to generate Fibonacci sequence by effective use of recursion.

Comment: @yuvi Why don't you add this in your question as well. If you want to go for recursion what you posted earlier will work if you replace array by `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

You must introduce a temporary variable like this:

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 2; i <= index; i++)
{
    result = fib(index - 1) + fib(index - 2);   //error comes here
}
return result;
```

But this is just the technical solution. As Bala pointed out, your algorithm as such does not work.

This could be a solution, if you are looking for a recursive one:

```
int fib(int index)
{
    switch(index) {
    case 0:
        return 0;
    case 1:
        return 1;
    default:
        return fib(index - 1) + fib(index -1);
    }
}
```

For a true dynamic solution you would store all calculated values into a static memo and reuse if it already exists.

```
int fib(int index)
{
    // Stores fib for given index
    static std::map<int, int> memo;

    if (index == 0) return 0;
    else if (index == 1) return 1;
    else {
       auto it = memo.find(index);
       if (it == memo.end()) {
           int r = fib(index - 1) + fib(index -2);
           memo[index] = r;
       } else return *it;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have missed the closing bracket for switch-case :p